# Can't log into rabbitmq management web UI with a new user

Tags: rabbitmq

Using the management web UI, I created a new user that should have access to the management plugin, and full permissions on the default virtual host, with no password set. However, when I attempt to login as that user (with the password field set to blank), the credentials are rejected. What am I missing?

Screenshots:

[image: Creating the test user]

[image: Login Failed]

Answer (score 0):

Oh, derp. It looks like a password is required if you want to use the web api. If you expand the overview section, you see this:

[image]